# Error at use RegistrationController::registerAction() overriting FOUserBundle

Tags: symfony-2.7

I try to overriding a RegistrationController from FOUserBundle but. has this error.

Notice: Declaration of Arquitectura\BaseBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction() should be compatible with that of FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction()

When chance and put to use the Request parameter, delete the cache , give that error

No route found for "GET /register/". I use Symfony 2.7.23

This is my new RegistrationController class

```
namespace Arquitectura\BaseBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
#use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{

    public function registerAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) {


        parent::registerAction($request);

        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, new UserEvent($user, $request));

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

}
```

I have to put something at the routing ???

Answer (score 0):

I see what was the error. Just have to say http://../app_dev.php/register   instead of http://../app_dev.php/register/  .Later send a error like

Attempted to load class "FOSUserEvents" from namespace "Arquitectura\BaseBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents"?

I just added the lines up

```
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
```

and works